# Submit Text Type Field OnChange

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, http-post

I'm trying to submit a form upon changing of a text field in HTML. Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
echo("<form name=\"editAgendaItem" . $this->Id . "\" id=\"editAgendaItem" . $this->Id . "\" method=\"post\" action=\"./?module=meetings&preload=edit&function=editAgendaItem&agendaitem=" . $this->Id . "\">\n");
echo("<table width=\"100%\" border=0>\n");
echo("<tr><td width=\"20px\">" . $this->Index . "</td><td><input type=\"text\" value=\"" . $this->Title . "\" name=\"agendaItemTitle" . $this->Id . "\" onChange=\"javascript:document.forms['editAgendaItem" . $this->Id . "'].submit();\" />");
echo("</td>\n");
...
```

Which evaluates to

```
<form name="editAgendaItem19" id="editAgendaItem19" method="post" action="./?module=meetings&preload=edit&function=editAgendaItem&agendaitem=19">
<table width="100%" border=0>
<tr><td width="20px">1</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="agendaItemTitle19" onChange="javascript:document.forms['editAgendaItem19'].submit()" /></td>
...
```

But more importantly

```
<form name="editAgendaItem19" id="editAgendaItem19" method="post" action="...">
<input type="text" value="" name="agendaItemTitle19" onChange="javascript:document.forms['editAgendaItem19'].submit()" />
...
```

- Which is eventually terminated by a  tag. My problem is that upon modifying the field and dropping focus, the form does not submit.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:

I've also tried using this method in the onChange event instead of in-line code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(FormName)
{
  document.forms[FormName].submit();
}
</script>
```

Edit:

Took the suggestion to use the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#agendaItemTitle24').live('blur',function()
      $('#editAgendaItem24').submit();
   });
});​

</script>
```

In my head, and

```
<form name="editAgendaItem24" id="editAgendaItem24" method="post" action="...">
<input type="text" value="" name="agendaItemTitle24" id="agendaItemTitle24" />
</form>
```

In my content. Still no dice.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings in your javascript console? If so, could you post them here?

Comment: No, I'm octern. That's why "- octern" shows up at the end of my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML could be like this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="...">
<input type="text" value="" name="myInput" id="myInput"/>
```

Now use jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myInput').live('blur',function(){
      $('#myForm').submit();
   });
});​
</script>
```

This is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtwLf/1/

Comment: I'll give this a try and post back. Thanks.

Comment: Gave this a spin - didn't yield any results. Form doesn't submit.

Comment: You are wrong @DigitalJedi805; Take a look at the jsFiddle link carefully. Put your cursor in textbox and then, go out. The form will try to go to the action

Comment: You are correct @Mohammed Saberi; but for some reason when I flip this over to my page it doesn't apply. I'll post another edit to my main post with what I'm trying. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
onkeyup="javascript:document.forms['editAgendaItem19'].submit()"
```

the onChange function only works if you remove focus by clicking somewhere else

Comment: That's the intention Snag - I wouldn't want to submit every time a user hits a key; as this would make entering an agenda item title like 'Call to Order' a two minute process; but thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `onBlur` event instead `onChange`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; may try this if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd really start by breaking out that javascript into a separate file and doing it on/after document ready. I think ive seen people say that its a bad thing nowadays to write inline javascript.

Anyone have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Well I have a submitForm method that is supposed to do this as well; but it doesn't actually send the form either. I'll edit the code above to show it.